# React Native - How to listen to permissions changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am implementing a screen in which a permission is required to display the main components.

When the permission is asked to the user, if it is not granted, how can I listen to the user permissions changes in the device settings, in order to render the main components when he goes back to the app (which was in background) and has granted the required permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is tu use AppState

```
  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    //Check permission here
  };
```

Comment: Little comment, you need to "check", NOT to request permission. Because requesting permission will cause change in AppState and you'll get cycle.